# Why does cin get strange values if input is a character and then stored in an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, input, integer, character, cin

I am studying C++ and writing some code using these examples: http://doeaccmantra.blogspot.it/2013/09/doeacc-mantra-learning-point-blog-for.html

I have this code:

```
// http://doeaccmantra.blogspot.it/2013/09/doeacc-mantra-learning-point-blog-for.html
/*
 * Prompt user for two integers and print their sum (Add2Integers.cpp)
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int integer1; // Declare a variable named integer1 of the type integer
   int integer2; // Declare a variable named integer2 of the type integer
   int sum;      // Declare a variable named sum of the type integer

   cout << "Enter first integer> ";   // Display a prompting message
   cin >> integer1;                   // Read input from keyboard (cin) into integer1
   cout << "Enter second integer> ";  // Display a prompting message
   cin >> integer2;                   // Read input into integer2

   sum = integer1 + integer2;         // Compute the sum

   // Print the result
   cout << "The sum of " << integer1 << " and " << integer2
        << " is " << sum << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Could you Explain me why if cin is given a character as input, I have this result?

```
Enter first integer> s
Enter second integer> The sum of 0 and 4283950 is 4283950
```

I studied languages like PHP and JS where type mismatch is a Fatal Error..

Is this not the case for C++? So "s" is interpreted as a number?

Also, it seems that the code ignores the second cin in this case...

**I think this question is to be closed, but I just want to clear this (interesting) one.**

Comment: Of course this isn´t ok in C++ too, but the program won´t crash etc. itself. Check failbit and ignore of cin.

Comment: Add error checking to your input statements and initialize your variables to a particular value.

Comment: I know I need to check for input validity, I asked why "s" is interpreted as a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a letter the stream extraction fails and the stream is left in an error state. That also means both `integer1` and `integer2` are left uninitialized which explains why you see garbage values when they're used.

There are member functions to check the stream's state (`good()`, `eof()`, `fail()`, `bad()`). The simplest and, I think, more correct method is this:

```
if (cin >> integer1) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

Comment: So what I see is some sort of error code for extraction failure...

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

`s` is not read and assigned to your int. The value you see is what your var was before you tried to read the stream. Both calls to your stream fail as the stream remains in error and you will need to clear it before you can read it again.

Try this:

```
int integer1 = 0; // init your var
int integer2 = 0; // init your var
while (!(cin >> integer1))
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid integer value";
    cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I asked why "s" is interpreted as a number

Comment: It isn't, you don't initialize your variables so when it fails you're left with whatever the value happened to be.

Comment: It is not. 's' is not read and the value of your int remains the default value.

Comment: So "4283950" is the default value for integers?

Comment: @uncletall: There is no "default" value for an uninitialized variable with automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Nomad: 4283950 is just a value that happened to be at that memory location. If you run in debug mode the compiler might initialize to some value, but that is compiler dependent I think.

Comment: @uncletall it's Nomid. xD

Ok, so when I initialize a variable, it is given a location in memory and that value was just the content of that address...

That means that in order to clear cin error state it is needed to execute `cin.clear()`